# How to 'initialize' a TypeScript object?

Tags: typescript

Seems, fetching a json from a mongodb datbase, and cast it will not trigger typescript constructor, why? What is wrong?

I have a `Team` class

```
export class Team {
    transformations: { [transformationId: string]: Transformation }
    typeTrees: { [ttMakerId: string]: TTMaker }

    constructor() {
        console.log('NewTree constructor called')
        this.transformations = {}
        this.typeTrees = {}
    }
}
```

I am downloading a json, which would conform as type to Team:

```
export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse<string | null>
) {
    const transformationId = req.query.transformationId as string
    const text = req.query.text as string
    try {
        const { mongoClient } = await connectToDatabase()
        const db: Db = mongoClient.db('datamapper')
        const collection = db.collection<Team>('team')
        const team: Team | null = await collection.findOne({
            name: 'responsive',
        })
```

But when I add a breakpoint to constructor Team, it will not be hit, why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const teamData = await collection.findOne({ name: 'responsive' });
const team = Object.assign(new Team(), teamData);
```

This will create a `new` instance of the `Team` class using the new keyword, and then assign the fetched data to it using `Object.assign()`. This should trigger the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

To initialize an object of `Team` class, you need to use the `new` operator like so:

```
const Team: Team = new Team();
```

by using the `new` operator it will trigger the constructor of the Team class.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This does not address the question, which is how to get that JSON data that has the same interface as instances of `Team` to be used in the instantiation of a `Team` object.